# Host REST API on same server as public website?

Tags: api, rest, security, host

I have a public website and also a REST API that I am developing. Is there any benefit (such as security or anything else) on having the API be on a different domain name & account, maybe even IP, than the public website?

Public:
http://www.mywebsite.com

API:
https://api.mywebsite.net, https://api.mywebsite2.com, ect

or

https://api.mywebsite.com

Does it matter? And are there any other precautions I need to take to make the API more secure?

Answer (score 0):

Is your API a public API or is it meant to be private?
- If private then ideally it needs to be behind a firewall this way it's totally hidden from web.

Domain: Not necessary however it is usually easier in the long run to put it on a subdomain for a couple of reasons, it's more defined that it's a sub part of the site and easier to move out to another server if you need to expand, load balance and so on.

Regarding security [Storm Path](https://stormpath.com/blog/secure-your-rest-api-right-way) have quite a good article on securing REST APIs however as a general rule.

- API Keys are safer than username and password.
- Temporary session keys make it less likely that an API key is intercepted. So API key + datetime stamp making a session key, which then use used for subsequent calls. Oauth2 have these patterns.
- TLS (SSL) is a good added measure on your API.

Comment: It's a private API for my mobile app. I'm sending a username/password in the header of each https call to authenticate the request.